# Modules containing subroutines and functions in fortran

Tags: module, fortran, procedure

I am learning correct use of subroutine, function and module, below is an simple example, no error occurs while compiling, after executing, the outcome is `4.57187637E-41` rather than  `pi`, I have looked up several references, haven't found out the mistake yet.

```
module wz
   implicit none
   private
   public :: print_out
   real,parameter :: pi = 3.14159
   contains
      subroutine print_out
      implicit none
      real :: area
      print *, area
      end subroutine print_out

      function f(x) result(area)
      implicit none

      real, intent(in):: x
      real            :: area

      area = pi * x ** 2
      end function f
end module wz

program test_module
use wz
implicit none
    real :: x
    x = 1.
   call print_out
end program test_module
```

Comment: How wrong? What is the expected outcome? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are printing is `area` just after declaration and before doing anything with it. You need to pass `x` to `f` function, and you can do that via the `print_out` subroutine:

```
module wz
   implicit none
   private
   public :: print_out
   real,parameter :: pi = 3.14159
   contains
      subroutine print_out(x)
      implicit none
      real, intent(in) :: x
      real :: area
      area = f(x)
      print *, area
      end subroutine print_out

      function f(x) result(area)
      implicit none

      real, intent(in):: x
      real            :: area

      area = pi * x ** 2
      end function f
end module wz

program test_module
use wz
implicit none
    real :: x
    x = 1.
   call print_out(x)
end program test_module
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way ,like I can add some attributes to the variable,to avoid this kind of mistakes, then the compiler will prompt a specific mistake.

Comment: The mistake of printing a variable that has only been declared? I don't think so. When a variable is declared, some memory is allocated for that variable and a "garbage" value is assigned (this is normally very close to 0).

Comment: Yes. There is a complet switch for -check uninit or some thing like that. I have it all the make files and use no checks and warnings once debug is complete. -Check bounds or -check all and -warn interfaces are also useful.

Comment: Didn't know about that one. Thanks.